# App Terminated due to Memory Pressure when using camera in iOS 7

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7, uiimagepickercontroller

I am facing error **App Terminated due to Memory Pressure**  when I capture some images using UIImagePickerController Camera.

I receive memory warnings first and then suddenly app crashes. This issue is in iOS 7 specifically as in iOS 6 it is working fine.

Does someone know why is this memory issue occuring in iOS 7 on using camera.

**Note:** I tried to minimize RAM usage because it may also be the reason for this memory pressure. But still getting warning.

Comment: Use the Allocations tool in Instruments to see exactly what is using up your RAM and when it gets allocated.

Comment: I tested in iPhone 5 too in iOS 7. It is working fine in iPhone 5. Only in iPad mini getting this warning.

Comment: this is quiet an issue with ipad mini

Comment: I had similar issue. iPhone reboot solves it =)

Answer (score 5):

I just posted this answer on a similar post ([iOS 7 UIImagePicker preview black screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21888366/ios-7-uiimagepicker-preview-black-screen/22000982#22000982)). Here's what I said:

About 5 months ago my team discovered a memory leak with UIImagePickerController. Each instantiation slowed down the app exponentially (i.e. first alloc-init had a 1 second delay, second had a 2 second delay, third had a 5 second delay). Eventually, we were having 30-60 delays (similar to what you're experiencing).

We resolved the issue by subclassing UIImagePickerController and making it a Singleton. That way it was only ever initialized once. Now our delay is minimal and we avoid the leak. If subclassing isn't an option, try a class property in your viewController and just lazy load it like so.

```
-(UIImagePickerController *)imagePicker{
    if(!_imagePicker){
        _imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
        _imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
}
    return _imagePicker;
}
```

Then you can just call it later like:

```
[self presentViewController:self.imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
```

From what I could tell, this is just an issue with the UIImagePickerController in iOS 7. Previous versions seems to be fine.

Comment: Fascinating stuff. - Note that your solution _assumes_ that the image picker will be used only for taking picture (camera), which is not necessarily the case.

Comment: Good point. You can always change it anytime by saying, self.imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary. The idea is though that your UIImagePickerController is only initialized once.

Comment: I will test thoroughly but it seems to have solved the problem.