# App Terminated due to Memory Pressure when using ZBar reader

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, ios7, xcode5

I'm using [ZBar reader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16166646/qr-code-scanning-in-ios-application) in my app for scanning QR Code. When I continuously open and close this scanner, the app terminated with message `App Terminated due to Memory Pressure`.

I searched over this and got an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22024326/756941) in which the same scenario that my app faces. ie, first time opening the scanner had a 1 second delay, second had a 2 second delay, third had a 5 second delay. and when going for fourth or fifth the app terminated.

But that answer is for `UIImagePickerController`. I'm using ZBar reader. Both are somewhat similar. I don't know how to modify my code to solve it.

Here is the code that I'm using,

```
codeReader = [ZBarReaderViewController new];
codeReader.readerDelegate=self;
codeReader.supportedOrientationsMask = ZBarOrientationMaskAll;
codeReader.showsCameraControls = NO;
codeReader.showsZBarControls=NO;
ZBarImageScanner *scanner = codeReader.scanner;
[scanner setSymbology: ZBAR_I25 config: ZBAR_CFG_ENABLE to: 0];
Class captureDeviceClass = NSClassFromString(@"AVCaptureDevice");
if (captureDeviceClass != nil) {
   AVCaptureDevice *device = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
   if ([device hasTorch] || [device hasFlash]){
     [device lockForConfiguration:nil];
     [device setTorchMode:AVCaptureTorchModeOff];
     [device setFlashMode:AVCaptureFlashModeOff];
     [device unlockForConfiguration];
   }
}
[self.view.window.rootViewController presentViewController:codeReader animated:YES completion:nil];

codeReader.cameraOverlayView = overlayview;
```

How should I change it to solve the issue?

Comment: You can use the 'leaks' instrument to try and identify where you are leaking memory.  The other thing you should do is see if you can create a single instance of a ZBar reader and the activiate/deactivate it rather than continually creating a new one as this is expensive in terms of time and memory.  In one of my apps I am using ZXingObjC and this is the approach I take to make things faster

Comment: Probably the easiest is to store in on a property of your app delegate and allocate it in your didFinishLaunching method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a single instance of your ZBar reader and store it as a property on your app delegate or you can use the singleton approach that was suggested in the UIPickerController answer.

In your appDelegate.h

@property (strong,nonatomic) ZBarReaderViewController *zbarReaderVC;

In your appDidFinishLaunching in appDelegate.m

```
self.zbarReaderVC = [ZBarReaderViewController new];
self.zbarReaderVC.readerDelegate=self;
self.zbarReaderVC.supportedOrientationsMask = ZBarOrientationMaskAll;
self.zbarReaderVC.showsCameraControls = NO;
self.zbarReaderVC.showsZBarControls=NO;
ZBarImageScanner *scanner = self.zbarReaderVC.scanner;
[scanner setSymbology: ZBAR_I25 config: ZBAR_CFG_ENABLE to: 0];
Class captureDeviceClass = NSClassFromString(@"AVCaptureDevice");
if (captureDeviceClass != nil) {
   AVCaptureDevice *device = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
   if ([device hasTorch] || [device hasFlash]){
     [device lockForConfiguration:nil];
     [device setTorchMode:AVCaptureTorchModeOff];
     [device setFlashMode:AVCaptureFlashModeOff];
     [device unlockForConfiguration];
   }
}
```

Then whenever you need the view

```
MyAppDelegate *d=[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;

ZBarReaderViewController codeReader=d.zbarReaderVC;

[self.view.window.rootViewController presentViewController:codeReader animated:YES completion:nil];

codeReader.cameraOverlayView = overlayview;
```

When you have finished with it remove it from the presenting view controller.

I haven't read through the docs of ZBar reader, but there is probably a method you need to call to start/stop it processing images even when it isn't presented.  I know there is with ZXingObjC.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I used the above code in viewdidload function that the view controller will be loaded only one time and the `imagePickerController didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` should be there to get the image. Anyway the memory issue got fixed.